# T4MVC - Folder under views in areas, can't create view property in Controller Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas, mvccontrib, t4mvc

I have a MVC Project that has T4MVC and I'm using Areas, under the Views in Areas, I'm using another folder to organize the views by feature. Because of this T4MVC can't identify the views for the specific controller. How do i solve this?

Here's a screenshot.

[image: T4MVC]

Comment: Please can you post your controller code.

Comment: @chxzy i don't see how that'd help, can you tell me why?

Comment: because it may give me insight to your issue.